# I'm new to the docusign API I'm having a problem when I'm sending a signature envelope

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

When I communicate as in the example https://docusign.github.io/postman-collections/ used postman works perfectly, but I wanted to do using the nodejs.

My problem is that I need to send a "template" document, sending some values ​​dynamically to my example templete:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1moL.png)

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3mI6.png

I got this code from the internet, put my information and this error is displayed:

    var docusign = require('docusign-esign');

// Note: Following values are class members for readability and easy testing
// TODO: Enter your DocuSign credentials
var UserName = 'foo@email.com';
var Password = 'SECRET1';

// TODO: Enter your Integrator Key (aka API key), created through your developer sandbox preferences
var IntegratorKey = 'SECRET2';

// for production environment update to 'www.docusign.net/restapi'
var BaseUrl = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi';

var RequestSignatureFromTemplate = function () {
  // TODO: Enter signer information and template info from a template in your account
  var signerName = 'Bob';
  var signerEmail = 'foo@email.com';
  var subject = "testing 123";
  var templateId = 'XXX';
  var templateRoleName = 'Seller';

  // initialize the api client
  var apiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
  apiClient.setBasePath(BaseUrl);

  // create JSON formatted auth header
  var creds = '{"Username":"' + UserName + '","Password":"' + Password + '","IntegratorKey":"' + IntegratorKey + '"}';
  apiClient.addDefaultHeader('X-DocuSign-Authentication', creds);

  // assign api client to the Configuration object
  docusign.Configuration.default.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient);

  // ===============================================================================
  // Step 1:  Login() API
  // ===============================================================================
  // login call available off the AuthenticationApi
  var authApi = new docusign.AuthenticationApi();

  // login has some optional parameters we can set
  var loginOps = new authApi.LoginOptions();
  loginOps.setApiPassword('true');
  loginOps.setIncludeAccountIdGuid('true');
  authApi.login(loginOps, function (error, loginInfo, response) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error: ' + error);
      return;
    }

    if (loginInfo) {
      // list of user account(s)
      // note that a given user may be a member of multiple accounts
      var loginAccounts = loginInfo.getLoginAccounts();
      console.log('LoginInformation: ' + JSON.stringify(loginAccounts));
```

Error when I run the code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aHFh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, but I would assume from the error message you need to remove the new from this line `var loginOps = new authApi.LoginOptions();` and make it `var loginOps = authApi.LoginOptions();`

May I suggest you use [these](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/docusign-esign) TypeScript types for the library so that you can check you are writing things in the syntax expected by the library.